# Octave - Fetch function

Tags: octave, yahoo-finance

I would like to use the Fetch function to get some data, looking at the example in the .m file I can't seem to run the function with the following command;

```
fetch(yahoo(), "yhoo", "01-Jul-2015", "10-Jul-2015", "w")
```

This gives me the following error;

> error: dates(_,4): but dates has size 0x0
> error: called from
> fetch_yahoo at line 69 column 12
> fetch at line 124 column 18

Does anyone have any idea what's going wrong here? I've tried changing the 'w' to 'd' but have no idea what's going wrong?

Comment: you really should add that you are using the "financial" package, right?

Comment: since the builtin test for "fetch" fails I guess yahoo has changed their API and fetch no longer works. You might file a bugreport on savannah

Comment: Yeah financial, ok I'll do that now, cheers.